# Where do systemd questions belong?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Questions regarding configuration of systemd services on an Ubuntu server, do they belong on:

- [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/)?
- [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)?
- [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/)?
- [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange sites do I post on?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-sites-do-i-post-on)

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog: The only mention of Linux on that page is in the question, mentioning that it is *not* about Linux. But since systemd is kind of a Linux thing, that means this isn't a dupe at all.

Answer (score 5):

I added `/questions/tagged/systemd` after each link and compared volume of questions with  that tag:

Results (as of writing):

- [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/systemd) - 834 questions
- [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/systemd) - 876 questions
- [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/systemd) - 1,268 questions
- [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/systemd) - 2,191 questions

**Conclusion:** I would say that Unix & Linux is the best place to post it, although the specifics of the question can affect where it will fit better.

Comment: So the correct place to post it just depends on popularity? If SO were to have more questions than Unix & Linux then would that become the proper place to post?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai no, not at all. It obviously depends on the specifics of the scope. I was just pointing out that it *is* posted frequently on various sites, but [U&L](http://s.tk/unix) seems to be the clear winner.

Comment: I got people downvoting my question cause it was SO instead of U&L, but clearly this shows that SO is also an appropriate place to post it! Anyway I closed it and moved it to U&L.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai also, I think for a while SO was considered *OK* for any questions, as the other communities opened it just made more sense to move them there as they are more on topic.